# Error while creating thumb from video ubuntu ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

using below line to generate thumb from the video saved in the public folder in the **laravel 4.2 application**.

```
exec("ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05 -i /var/www/html/project/public/".$directory."".$filename." -vf 'select=not(mod(n\,1000)),scale=320:240' /var/www/html/project/public/".$d.$thumb." >> log_file.log 2>&1 &",$output, $exit_code);
```

but **"log_file.log"** contains the following line:

```
cannot create user data directory: /var/www/snap/ffmpeg/411: Read-only file system
```

I used snap to install the **ffmpeg**.